# IllegalAccessError in Java SE app with Weld implementation

Tags: xml, hibernate, entitymanager, weld, weld-se

I am trying to run a standalone app that has Weld implementation of CDI, and in that app I need EntityManager to work with Oracle database.

When I run my app (via Weld main method), following is shown in cmd line:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder from class javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder$ConfigurationError
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaringClass0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaringClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getEnclosingClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getSimpleBinaryName(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.isMemberClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.isNonStaticInnerClass(Reflections.java:139)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.isBeanCandidate(BeanDeployer.java:98)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.addClass(BeanDeployer.java:78)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.addClasses(BeanDeployer.java:135)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployment.createBeans(BeanDeployment.java:184)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.deployBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:349)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.api.helpers.ForwardingBootstrap.deployBeans(ForwardingBootstrap.java:70)
    at org.jboss.weld.environment.se.Weld.initialize(Weld.java:133)
    at org.jboss.weld.environment.se.StartMain.go(StartMain.java:41)
    at org.jboss.weld.environment.se.StartMain.main(StartMain.java:52)
```

What could cause such an error?

Here is my persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="oracleUnit"
                  transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

    <class>entities.MyEntity</class>

    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.platform"
                  value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.oracle.OraclePlatform" />

        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                  value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="TEST" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="test" />

        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Here are dependencies:

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.weld.se</groupId>
        <artifactId>weld-se-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Here is how I create Entity Manager, fairly standard:

```
  EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("oracleUnit");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating Weld dependency to the newest one solved the issue.

Dependencies now look as following:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.weld.se</groupId>
        <artifactId>weld-se-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0.Alpha14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
        <artifactId>jandex</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```